# .htaccess redirect with query string not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do an .htaccess redirect from /modules.php?name=Farmtoschool
to a new URL.

I've looked at the other posts here but it doesn't seem to work. (full htaccess below, redirect at the bottom)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/modules.php$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^name=Farmtoschool$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://mynewdomain.com/modules.php?name=Farmtoschool   [R=301,L]
```

this is the link that I want to redirect:

```
http://myolddomain.com/modules.php?name=Farmtoschool
```

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: It goes to the WordPress 404 page.

Comment: Can you post full htaccess and tell which URL is causing 404?

Comment: Hello anubhava, I've updated with the full htaccess and the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder your rules by keeping redirect rule before WP rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=Farmtoschool$
RewriteRule ^modules\.php$ http://farmtoschoolbc.ca/modules.php?name=Farmtoschool [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```